# How to increase the performance of random forest classifier?

Tags: feature-selection, python, random-forest, text-mining, scikit-learn

I have a text classification task.  These are the metrics for different languages at present:

```
class1: 0.6823
class2: 0.7450
class3: 0.66
class4: 0.6719
```

How can I increase the performance of my random forest classifier in order to reach 90% accuracy? I already tried increasing the number of estimators and playing with the hyper-parameters that `scikit` provides, but I cannot significantly increase its performance. What hyper-parameter do I configure in order to increase its performance?

This is my current setup:

```
# For tfidf: 
tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer(norm=u'l1', use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, 
                             sublinear_tf=False, min_df=2, stop_words=set(my_stop_words))

# For RF:
rbf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10000, criterion='entropy', max_depth=10000, 
                             max_leaf_nodes=None, bootstrap=True, oob_score=False, 
                             n_jobs=1, random_state=None, verbose=0, min_density=None, 
                             compute_importances=None)
```

What about using adaboost + random forest classifier in order to increase the performance? Is that possible?

Comment: A max depth of 10000 seems very large

Comment: What makes 90% accuracy a magic number?  That level of accuracy is likely seriously over-fit to the training data.

Comment: How did you settle on RF as your model of choice? Another algorithm likely wouldn't improve your results up to 90%, but you could see a few percentage points improvement.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using `scikit-learn`, and you're trying to tweak the parameters of your classifier, you should consider using [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html). GridSearchCV allows to try out various parameter setups and pick the best one.

I really doubt this will let you achieve 90% accuracy, though. You should rather rethink whether the dataset you're using, and your feature extraction routines are sufficient to aim at such an accuracy level.